# Position independent code in 16-bit real mode, bootloading/floppy read

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, position-independent-code

The following source files are assembled separately (into raw binaries) and loaded onto sectors 1 and 2, respectively, of a virtual floppy. This floppy then serves as the boot medium for a qemu-system-i386 VM.

The "bootloader" reads the "first program" from sector 2 of the floppy, and then it jumps to the memory containing the code just read. The following code works as desired (i.e. the "first program" welcome message is printed), but I had to specify `ORG 0x001E` in the source of the "first program" (obtained by examining the bootloader's code in a hex editor). 0x001E is the offset of the `temp` buffer, which holds the code read from the floppy.

"bootloader":

```
BITS 16

bootloader_main:
    mov bx, 0x07C0      ; Set data segment to bootloader's default segment
    mov ds, bx


    mov ah, 0x02        ; BIOS int13h "read sector" function
    mov al, 1           ; Number of sectors to read
    mov cl, 2           ; Sector to read
    mov ch, 0           ; Cylinder/track
    mov dh, 0           ; Head
    mov dl, 0           ; Disk number (here, the floppy disk)
    mov bx, 0x07C0      ; Segment containing the destination buffer
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, temp        ; Destination buffer offset
    int 0x13

    jmp temp

    ret
;end bootloader_main




temp: times 60 db 17

times 510-($-$$) db 0       ; Pad rest of sector and add bootloader   
dw 0xAA55                      signature
```

"first program":

```
BITS 16
ORG 0x001E       ; Assume that this code will be located 0x001E bytes     
                   after start of bootloader (in RAM)

mov bx, string      ; Print a welcome string
mov ah, 0x0E
print_loop:
    mov al, byte [bx]
    int 0x10
    inc bx
    cmp byte [bx], 0
    jne print_loop
;end print_loop


string: db "This is the first program.", 0
```

Alternatively, I could use `ORG 0x200` and `0x200` for the buffer instead of `temp` (i.e. load the program into RAM just after the bootloader), but neither of these hacks seems sustainable when it comes to creating useful operating systems. How do I avoid this kind of hardcoding of addresses?

Comment: Please tag the processor architecture when posting assembly questions.

Comment: I would imagine base address is something that would need to be specified with the bootloader. Most of my work in this area has been on embedded systems, and I know the BIOS does a lot of stuff for you. For me, when I use a bootloader, it usually has documentation telling me where the entry point is expected to be.

Comment: So if someone was assembling a program that would be loaded onto the floppy and read by the bootloader, they would be told to add something like `ORG 512` (or some other definite address) to their source code? And the bootloader would always load the program to the same part of memory? It's difficult to imagine how modern operating systems evolved from this, but I guess I should go read more about the history.

Comment: again, my experience is with embedded systems, so if I get a bootloader from NXP to put on a Kinetis part, the documentation will tell me that the bootloader will be placed from 0x0000 to 0x3fff, and that I need to link my program to have the address of its entry point at 0x4000. The trick with segments is the way that makes sense in your case, but that's a feature not found in most embedded systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid hard coding of addresses by using segments. Load the "first program" at an address that's a multiple of 16 and load DS with corresponding segment (address / 16) and then far jump to `segment:0` where `segment` is where you loaded the program. Use `ORG 0` in the loaded program.

For example:

```
BITS 16

bootloader_main:
    mov ax, 0x07C0      ; Set data segment to bootloader's default segment
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 0x02        ; BIOS int13h "read sector" function
    mov al, 1           ; Number of sectors to read
    mov cl, 2           ; Sector to read
    mov ch, 0           ; Cylinder/track
    mov dh, 0           ; Head
    mov bx, program_seg ; load program at program_seg:0
    mov es, bx
    xor bx, bx
    int 0x13

    mov ax, program_seg
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax          ; set stack to end of program_seg
    mov sp, 0
    jmp program_seg:0

bootloader_end:
program_seg equ (bootloader_end - bootloader_main + 0x7c00 + 15) / 16

times 510-($-$$) db 0       ; Pad rest of sector and add bootloader   
dw 0xAA55                   ;   signature
```

```
BITS 16
ORG 0

mov bx, string      ; Print a welcome string
mov ah, 0x0E
print_loop:
    mov al, byte [bx]
    int 0x10
    inc bx
    cmp byte [bx], 0
    jne print_loop
;end print_loop


string: db "This is the first program.", 0
```

I've removed the `mov dl, 0` instruction because you shouldn't hard code this value. The BIOS will pass the drive number of the boot device in DL, so you don't need to change it.

Comment: Another common trick is to copy your boot loader code somewhere else (you're copying so you know where) and load the second sector over the original boot sector, again giving you a known location. Lots of approaches.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer The question seemed to about how to load a program at a non-hardcoded "known" address. Aside from how the load segment is chosen, this example is essentially how MS-DOS handles loading .COM files.

Answer (score 0):

This example allows you to enter any amount of code between
jmp Load_Buffer & Load_Buffer, so long as it doesn't overrun last 4 bytes of boot sector.

**BOOTLOADER**

```
    BOOTSEG     equ 0x7c0
    LOW_MEM     equ 18
    DISKIO      equ 19
```

Determine how many 4k pages are avaliable and convert this to a segment
address. In my case it's 0x8FC0.

```
xor     cx, cx
mov     cl, 64
int     LOW_MEM             ; Get # of 4k segments to top of memory
sub     ax, cx
shl     ax, 6                       ;
```

Always disable interrupt when modifiying stack pointer.  This puts stack in a pretty safe place at top of memory less 64k

```
cli
mov     ss, ax
xor     sp, sp
sti
```

At this point CS could be 0 or it could be 0x7c0 depending on bios vendor, but that doesn't really matter because only ES:BX is important at this point

```
mov     ax, Load_Buffer
shr     ax, 4
add     ax, BOOTSEG
mov     es, ax  
mov     ax, 0x201                   ; Read one sector
mov     cx, 2                       ; Starting @ cylinder 0, sector 2
xor     dh, dh                  ; Head 0 and BIOS has already passed device.
```

An alternative here would have been to load ES with 0x7c0 and BX with Load_Buffer as in your example, however in our case ES = BOOTSEG + Load_Buffer / 16.

```
xor     bx, bx
int     DISKIO                  ; Read sector 2
jmp     Load_Buffer
```

Alignment on page boundry will guarantee loader will always work no matter how much is added above Load_Buffer unless it happens to over-run last 4 bytes of boot sector. Alignment only needs be on page boundary, so 16 would have worked just as well.

```
align   32
Load_Buffer:
```

It's probably a good idea to fill sector with NOP's incase code runs away, there won't be a segment fault.

```
times   508 - ($-$$)    db  144     ; NOP's 0x90
int     25                      ; Incase codes runs away we'll reboot
dw      0xAA55                  ; Boot sig (no required by some emulators)
```

**First Program**

Going to use LODSB, not that is more correct than your way, but just uses less code.

```
mov     si, string
push    es
pop     ds                      ; DS:SI now points to string
mov     ah, 14                  ; TTY output

Loop:
lodsb                           ; Read from DS:SI
test    al, 255             ; Test if these any of these bits are on.
jz      .Done
int     16
jmp     Loop
```

The period before label is just NASM functionality for declaring local labels

```
.Done:
hlt
jmp     $

string  db  'This is the first program', 0
```

Comment: `int 12h` actually returns the amount of KiB of low memory, not amount of 4 KiB pages. Shifting left by 6 is correct to get from KiB (2 ** 10) to paragraphs (2 ** 4) however. (But `shl ax, 6` is not 8086-clean.)